# spinning network icon with reachability

Tags: ios, networking, reachability

Ok so my question is obviously about the reachability class.  I'm using it in an ipad app but a constant connection isn't actually required, just occasional xml sent to a server.  What I'm noticing is that the little network indicator in the top left is **eternally spinning**.  Is reachability causing it?  My appDelegate class is listening for the connection, but I'm worried about additional battery usage.  Any thoughts?

```
didfinishlaunchingwithoptions {

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

    hostReachable = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"www.apple.com"];
    [hostReachable startNotifier];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reachability does not have any references to show/hide networkActivityIndicator so it must be coming from somewhere else in your project.  Use Xcode's search to search the whole project.